# Make an OAuth request using flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, oauth

I'm working with bricklink api http://static.bricklink.com/alpha/default/api_wiki.html

I'm unable to implement it in flutter, due to lack of expertise. Here is the request implementation in node.js and I want to replicate this in flutter.

```
const OAuth = require('oauth');
const fs = require('fs');

const http = require('http');

const host = '127.0.0.1';
const port = '7070';

const server = http.createServer((_req, res) => {
    var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth('', '', 'consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', '1.0', null, 'HMAC-SHA1');

    oauth.get('https://api.bricklink.com/api/store/v1/categories', 'token_value', 'token_secrete', function(error, data, res) {
        if (error) return false;

        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        saveData(json);

    });

    function saveData(data) {
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
        fs.writeFileSync('inventory.json', jsonData);

        res.statusCode = 200 || 201;
        // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
        res.end('Done');
        console.log('Done');
    }
});
```

I want to implement this request in flutter.

Thank You

Comment: Are you looking for a contractor, or do you have a question? If you have a question, your first step needs to be to try and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Due to lack of expertise with OAuth request, I failing to even try such a thing.

Comment: It's unlikely that people will write this all for you. Might be time to actually hire a contractor or freelancer! I hope an OAuth1 client exists for flutter as it's quite old at this point.